# Не сохраняется файл на девайс в Android

Tags: android, файлы, xls, save

Программа генерирует документ формата .xls во внутреннюю память планшета. На моем планшете все хорошо сохраняется во внутреннюю память. На других - не получается. Пробовал и external и internal storage, да и разными способами... Помогите найти действующее решение
Мой конечный код, который так и не сохраняет на других девайсах:
 `String fileName = getFIOFromPhoto.getText().toString() + "_" + getDateOfPhoto.getText().toString() + "_ФРД.xls";*`

```
                try {
                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                    File file;

                    File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"frd_alrino/");
                    directory.mkdirs();

                    if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "все окай", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();/// сообщение об успешном сохранении
                    }

                    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sdCard.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();/// сообщение об успешном сохранении
                        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/", fileName);
                                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"DCIM/", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();/// сообщение об успешном сохранении

                    } else {
                        file = new File(getFilesDir()+fileName);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Записано 2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();/// сообщение об успешном сохранении
                    }

                    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file);
```

Comment: И права на запись в external storage есть? На каких версиях системы работает, а на каких нет?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

Comment: Права есть. Насчет версий позже напишу

Comment: На версиях Android >6 данной строчки недостаточно.

Comment: Версии точно больше 6. Вроде 11 мое устройство... А что необходимо указать?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html